what if your sunnah ghusl is incomplete but you washed all parts of your body but you do a fard ghusl shortly after that is your ghusl valid?
My father usually knocks on my door to let me know that i should be finished, but it happend when my sunnah ghusl was incomplete but at the same time the water reached all parts of my body and also my mouth and nose and i did a fard ghusl shortly after, does that make my ghusl invalid, and I need someone to answer immediatly because m worried it might be invalid
